# PrimeNg calendar in angular displaying dates in 6 rows

Tags: angular, calendar, angular7, primeng

I am using the PrimeNg calendar in my Angular7 project. by default, the calendar displays the date in  6 rows for all months, which is quite unusual. even if the last date of the selected month ends within 5 rows, 6th row displaying. How to avoid this 6th row any ideas

```
   <p-calendar  class="WorkTimeCalender" [(ngModel)]="workingDate"  
    [inline]="true"  [disabledDays]="[0,6]"  >                                       
    </p-calendar>
```

[image]

Comment: can you please put your code here

Comment: @Tharaka, code added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply the following property to the calendar to not show that 6th row:

```
 [showOtherMonths]="false"
```

Comment: I don't want to show any empty spaces in the 1st and 5th row of previous month dates wanted to exclude 6th row as it contains all next month dates

Comment: @user2038538 I checked my answer, and 6th row was hidden. Now you say a different case.

Comment: yes ,6th row was hidden, but in the 1st and 5th-row previous month dates shows empty. I don't want any empty spaces on the calendar.

Comment: @user2038538 you asked "How to avoid this 6th row?", and I answered it correctly, now you ask a new question.

Comment: @user2038538 that behaviour is a bug in primeng 7, and it looks like it is fixed in version 8. [github issue](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/6501). So you can upgrade to primeng V8 and fix this bug. And don't forget to mark and upvote this answer.

Comment: Thank you. 6th row removed after updating PrimeNg to the latest version